# how to add mouse event for a button?

Tags: javafx

i have a fxml file and in my fxmlcontroller class i implement Initializable and i have a stackpane and a button in my fxml file i want to add a Mouse pressed event to my btn but it not has any setOnAction method (i think because i didn't extends application in my class)
now i want to add mouse event handler but i can't . any ideas? thanks in advance.

```
    public class menuController implements Initializable{
        static int seconds=0;
        @FXML StackPane stackPane;
        @FXML Button btn;
        @Override
     public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
     btn.setOnAction(nothing found);  
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be importing wrong Button. Import JavaFX's button as

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
```

then add event handler like

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

     @Override
     public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
         System.out.println("Button clicked");
     }
 });
```